# Error getting the amount of GB used in one account

Tags: php

When I upload a video in my website, its size is saved in the database.
And then, I use these functions to **get the amount of gygabites left in the account used**.

```
    public static function Capacidad($user){
        $sql = "SELECT tipocuenta.id, tipocuenta.capacidad FROM tipocuenta, canal WHERE tipocuenta.id = canal.id_tipocuenta AND canal.id = '$user'";
        $resultado = self::Conexion($sql);

        if(isset($resultado)){ $datos = $resultado->fetch(); }

        $capacidad = $datos["capacidad"];

        return $capacidad;
    }

    public static function CapacidadUsada($user){
        $sql = "SELECT sum(tamaño) FROM video WHERE usuario_id = '$user'";
        $resultado = self::Conexion($sql);
        return $resultado;
    }

    public static function CapacidadUsadaGB(){
        $capacidad_total = Database::Capacidad($_SESSION["usuario"]);
        $capacidad_usada = Database::CapacidadUsada($_SESSION["usuario"]);

        $capacidad_usadaGB = number_format($capacidad_usada / 1073741824, 2)."GB";

        return $capacidad_usadaGB;
    }
```

I get the **amount of GB that an user can use** and the **amount of GB that the user have used uploading** videos.
But it doesnt work...
It prints me this error:

```
Notice: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int
```

Comment: Compare the functions `Capacidad()` and `CapacidadUsada()` in how they deal with the database. In the first you're doing it right by calling `fetch()` on the result. In the second function you forgot to do that, so what you're returning is the PDOStatement, not the actual value. You could have gathered that from the error message as well. ;) (Also, I have to say it's really tricky to read code in a foreign language...even if it's still PHP. Very distracting. It's a good practice to write your code in English, so other developers can understand it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `CapacidadUsada()` returns a result set, not a number. That's why the line `number_format($capacidad_usada / 1073741824, 2)` would throw an error.

Update the `CapacidadUsada()` function to return a number, just like `Capacidad()`:

```
public static function CapacidadUsada($user){
    $sql = "SELECT sum(tamaño) AS usada FROM video WHERE usuario_id = '$user'";
    $resultado = self::Conexion($sql);

    if(empty($resultado)) 
        throw new Exception('Error retrieving usage.');
    $datos = $resultado->fetch();

    return $datos['usada'];
}
```

Comment: Just one thing, is it well done the conversion to GB?

Comment: To make sure it's done right, replace it with `$capacidad_usada / (1024*1024*1024)`